# Printing elements of a list in C

Tags: c

Basically in the code below I am trying to insert some names and some ages in a list and to print them out. However, my program prints just the last name and age of the list. Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/* these arrays are just used to give the parameters to 'insert',
   to create the 'people' array 
*/

#define HOW_MANY 7
char *names[HOW_MANY]= {"Simon", "Suzie", "Alfred", "Chip", "John", "Tim",
              "Harriet"};
int ages[HOW_MANY]= {22, 24, 106, 6, 18, 32, 24};

typedef struct person
{
  char *name;
  int age;
  struct person *next;
}Person;

Person *headp = NULL;
static Person* insert(Person *p, char *name, int age) 
{
  p = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person)); 
  if (p == NULL)
    abort();
  p->name = name;
  p->age = age;
  p->next = headp;
  return p;
}  

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
  Person *people=headp;
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
  {
    people = insert (people, names[i], ages[i]);
  }
  while (people != NULL)
  {
    printf ("name: %s, age: %i\n", people->name, people->age);
    people= people->next;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the passed variable `p` with the address returned by `malloc` (memory leak and you loose the previous head), change to:

```
static Person *insert(Person *head, char *name, int age) 
{
  Person *p = malloc(sizeof(Person)); /* Don't cast malloc */

  if (p == NULL)
    abort();
  p->name = name;
  p->age = age;
  p->next = head;
  return p;
}
```

Comment: It is working ....but it prints out the elements in reverse order...i.e. the first element is the last one...

Comment: Then change `for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) `  to `for (int i = 6; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: @RalucaDamarisLupeş: How is this surprising? You have designed your `insert` function to act like `prepend` rather than `append`.

Comment: You are welcome, but the inverse loop is not a good style, as pointed out by @giant_teapot, (to learn and practice) change your design to act like prepend.

Comment: Hint: if you want to insert at the *end* of the list, move to the end of the list *before* inserting. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to reassign `headp` to `people` once you are done inserting, because else the `people` pointer still points to the last person (because you advance the `people` pointer in every insert).